# Can't reinstall Ubuntu because Windows is hibernated

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu, but I'm having a big problem.

My computer has two disks. I initially installed Ubuntu on my HDD. Then I uninstalled it and deleted all the information from my computer to try to reinstall Ubuntu on my SSD.

The problem happens when launching the bootable USB. It shows this:

> The disk contains an unclean file system (0,0). Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. PLease resume and shutdown windows fully (no hibernationor fast restarting.) Could not mount read-write, trying to read only Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

**"Windows is hibernated"** is the main issue here.

Windows must be completely shut down if you want to install Ubuntu or if you want to boot an Ubuntu installation in dual boot config with Windows.

You can't hibernate your Windows operating system before you try to use or  install Ubuntu.

This also means that you must disable "Fast Startup" in Windows because Fast Startup is actually a hybrid suspend.

To fix this, you need to boot into Windows and make sure you shut it down *completely* before you try to install or use Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just disabled the Fast Startup in windows, but I still can't install Ubuntu...

Comment: Does this solve the problem you wrote about on your question, or do you have a new problem now? If this solves the problem you asked about, that's great. If you have a new problem you can ask a new question about that.

Comment: Make sure you [verify the ISO you download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu), then follow the official tutorial to [Install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). Before installation, prerequisites are that you must have enough unpartitioned free space for Ubuntu and you need to know how to boot a USB flash drive using your motherboard firmware. You also need to boot the USB in the same mode that Windows is already installed (Typically UEFI). If you need help with another installation issue, please reference the tutorial when asking.